# Dynamic Cross Tab Query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic, pivot

i need to create a dynamic cross tab query where columns will not always be fixed in number so cant hard code using case when. i ve googled, it did find a blog about doing the same in SQL Server but i was wondering if there is any such article blog on doing the same in Oracle. Have not worked in SQL Server. Fol is the info about my problem.

the hard coded cross tab query i wrote

```
SELECT

LU_CITY.CITY_NAME as "City",
count(CASE WHEN emp.emp_category='Admin'  THEN emp.emp_id END) As "Admins",
count(CASE WHEN emp.emp_category='Executive'  THEN emp.emp_id END) As "Executive",
count(CASE WHEN emp.emp_category='Staff'  THEN emp.emp_id END) As "Staff",
count(emp.emp_id) As "Total"

FROM emp, LU_CITY

where

   LU_CITY.CITY_ID = EMP.CITY_ID(+)
group by
LU_CITY.CITY_NAME, LU_CITY.CITY_ID
order by
LU_CITY.CITY_ID
```

tables

```
        emp (emp_id, emp_name, city_id, emp_category)
        lu_city(city_id,city_name)
```

query result

```
          ------------------------------------------
          City | Admins | Executive | Staff . . . .
          ------------------------------------------ 
          A    |    1   |   2       | 3
          B    |    0   |   0       | 4
          .    |    .   |   .       | . 
          .
          .
```

The emp_category can be added by the user as per their need. the query should be such that it should generate all such categories dynamically.

Any guidance in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: link to the blog would enlighten us too ;-)

Comment: i have edited the question with more elaborate picture of the problem statment

Comment: @LandonAshes How will these results be used?  If you just need this information for other processing, than regular dynamic SQL like kothvandir's solution should work.  But if you really need a variable number of columns in adhoc SQL statements, you'll need to use "method 4 dynamic SQL".  The data cartridge solution at this site may be helpful: http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=422

Comment: @ jonearles Actually i this generate result of sql is to be later on printed as pdf report for the user.i need a query that would give me a list of result with varying columns every time data changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use dynamic cursors to execute dynamic SQL compiled from a VARCHAR2 variable:

```
DECLARE 
       w_sql             VARCHAR2 (4000);
       cursor_           INTEGER;
       v_f1    NUMBER (6);
       v_f2    NUMBER (2);
       v_some_value_2_filter_4    NUMBER (2);
       rc      INTEGER         DEFAULT 0;
BEGIN
        -- join as many tables as you need and construct your where clause
        w_sql :='SELECT f1, f2 from TABLE1 t1, TABLE2 t2, ... WHERE t1.f1 =' || v_some_value_2_filter_4 ; 

       -- Open your cursor
       cursor_ := DBMS_SQL.open_cursor;
       DBMS_SQL.parse (cursor_, w_sql, 1);
       DBMS_SQL.define_column (cursor_, 1, v_f1);
       DBMS_SQL.define_column (cursor_, 2, v_f2);
      -- execute your SQL
       rc := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE (cursor_);

       WHILE DBMS_SQL.fetch_rows (cursor_) > 0
       LOOP
          -- get values from record columns
          DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE (cursor_, 1, v_f1);
          DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE (cursor_, 2, v_f2);

          -- do what you need with v_f1 and v_f2 variables

       END LOOP;

END;
```

Or you can use [execute immediate](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm), easier to implement if you just need to check a value or execute and insert/update/delete query

```
    w_sql :='select f1 from table where f1 = :variable';
    execute immediate w_sql into v_f1 using 'valor1'
```

Here more info about dynamic cursors:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm