# How to make dynamic select rows to column?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query like this

```
select
    to_char(WAKTU,'DD-MM-RRRR HH24:MI') waktu, a.KODE_ALAT,
    min(case when aa.KODE_STATISTIK = 'HOIST' then a.NILAI else null end) HOIST,
    min(case when aa.KODE_STATISTIK = 'TROLLEY' then a.NILAI else null end) TROLLEY,
    min(case when aa.KODE_STATISTIK = 'GANTRY' then a.NILAI else null end) GANTRY,
    min(case when aa.KODE_STATISTIK = 'ENGINE' then a.NILAI else null end) ENGINE,
    min(case when aa.KODE_STATISTIK = 'COUNTER' then a.NILAI else null end) COUNTER
from 
    TRECORD_STATISTIK_ALAT a
left outer join 
    TALAT_STAT aa on aa.KODE_STATISTIK = a.KODE_STATISTIK
join 
    valat v on v.kode_alat=a.kode_alat
where 
    v.jenis_alat ='RTG' 
    and (waktu between to_date('24-11-2018','DD-MM-RRRR hh24:mi') and to_date('04-12-2018','DD-MM-RRRR hh24:mi'))
group by 
    a.waktu, a.KODE_ALAT
order by 
    a.waktu desc;
```

`Data of KODE_STATISTIK` is dynamic, how to select all of `kode_statistik` of `talat_stat`, in my code I must declare all of `kode_statistik`.

Comment: Do you mean that there are not only 5 values for`KODE_STATISTIK`, but could be more in the future?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258576/dynamic-cross-tab-query-in-oracle

Comment: @TheImpaler yes,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic Cross Tab Query in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258576/dynamic-cross-tab-query-in-oracle)

Comment: Why do you use format `to_date(...,'DD-MM-RRRR hh24:mi')` if you don't specify any time in your string?

Comment: I think, [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9533645800346454735) you can find some useful information